# Transactions and detach objects JPA

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

Good morning in my timezone.

Technologies : EJB 3.0
               JPA provider ->(openjpa)
               Container -> WAS
SNIPPET OF CODE:

```
@Stateless(name = "ejb/BeanName")
public class A implements AInterface{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "main")
    private EntityManager emanager;

    public String getData(D d){
       try{
        C c = new C();
        F f = emanager.find(F.class,d.getId());(1)
        f.setSomeData(c);(2)
        getMethodTwo(d,f);(3)
        }finally{
          emanager.clear();(5)   
        }

    }

    public String getMethodTwo(D d,F f){
         Query q = emanager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE ...");
         q.executeUpdate();(4)     

    }

}
```

In my company project , i am making changes to this snippet of code.
My changes was the creation of method "getMethodTwo" and his invocation(3).The problem is that in pace (4) the JPA throws an exception because there are changes on the object "f" that was loaded through the EntityManager(1), so it is attached to the context, and because there are changes when we call the executeUpdate(4) the JPA will try to run the SQL statements of the changes on the object "f".Before my changes , this code works because there is a finalize that clear the persistence context(5).I think this is a poor way of code. I know if i call the entitymanager.clear() before i call my method it will work but i think this is not the right solution and the right way of using JPA. What should i do ?

Best regards
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you should flush the object state to DB before calling the update.

```
emanager.flush();
```

and refresh its state after the operation

```
emanager.refresh(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is if i "flush" the changes made to the "f" object will be sent to the database through SQL statements (UPDATE AND INSERT) and the "f" object is not yet prepared to be used in the statement because the required fields are not all fullfilled and a CONSTRAINT NULL exception will be thrown.The point is to avoid the FLUSH.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem using the annotation TransactionAttributeType NOT_SUPPORTED, because the method just make SELECT statements.